# Can iPhone X be set to show battery percentage on the status notch?

Tags: battery, iphone

Is there a way?

In Settings, I can't find such an option and it won't show the percentage there too. Can it be done besides using 3rd party app such as [System Status Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-status-lite-hw-monitor/id407752428?mt=8)?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, as of iOS 11.1, there's no way of showing the battery percentage by default.

One way to see the battery percentage is to pull-down slightly on the right 'wing' (with the battery icon).  Once the screen changes to the **Control Center**, you'll be able to see the battery percentage.
[image]

Another way to find this out is to just ask **Siri**.  You can say "What's my battery life" and the response will include the percentage of power remaining.

The remaining way is to charge your iPhone.  When you charge it, the battery percentage is **briefly** displayed on the lock screen.

Comment: interesting... I think the control center solution should work fine.  I really just do need to know whether it is 12% or 2% in order to find out how quick I need to go back to the car or office to charge it.

Comment: a side note is how are you able to capture a screenshot like the one you have in the answer?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 That's an image from an iMore article about the iPhone X.  I was trying to find a picture that showed the battery percentage and that's the first one I found.